# Refactoring a module into a class: Changing shared fields to instance fields

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, refactoring

I'm currently refactoring an old Visual Basic DLL (VB.Net), which stores all of its data in one module called *Globaldefinitions* as public fields. There are about 200 fields, referenced thousands of times all around the code:

```
Public Module Globaldefinitons
     Public a As Short
     ...
     Public zz10 As Double
End Module
```

In the DLL itself, after importing *Globaldefinitions*, these fields are referenced with their name (No module prefix):

```
a = 5
```

I need to change the module into a class with non-shared fields. This means, each and every of these thousands of references needs to reference the instance of that class:

```
globalDefinitionsInstance.a = 5
```

How do I go about this efficiently?

Regular expressions operating on the source fall flat. Refactoring tools like Re-Sharper or CodeRush don't seem to offer this functionality. Visual Studio 2010 cannot do it automatically either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way I would go about changing this.  For every field in `GlobalDefinitions` do the following

- Use Visual Studio Refactor Rename to rename it to a unique name `Bad_Name_a`.  This will turn all of the hard to match names into very easy to match names
- Do a global search and replace for `Bad_Name_a` to `globalDefinitionsInstance.Bad_Name_a`.  No need for even a regex here.  The name and replacement are unique
- Use Visual Studio Refactor Rename to rename it to the better name of your choosing

Comment: Thank you. It will still be a lot of work, but at least safer than a simple search & replace.

Answer (score 0):

I would first use the built-in VS 2010 rename functionality to rename `a` to something that is as unique as possible, such as `ReplaceThisSillyPropertyNameNow`. Then you can do a global search and replace on the new name with your desired replacement.